# How to Transfer 'A' app to 'B' app within same itunesConnect account?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

What i want to do it to transfer the 'A' app to 'B' like 'A' app features layouts etc should be transfer to 'B' app, and the existing user of both app will get one app update in result, which will be 'B' app, if they will find 'A' or 'B' will find only 'A' in result on appstore, is this possible? is Apple is providing such kind of thing? if yes then how will do it? please guide me with your experience.

Comment: What you mean is that you want to change the code of "A" app to "B" app, but want to send "B" app as an update to "A" app?

Comment: @Munahil yes i need to do the same as you understood..

Comment: Okay, this is easy, I will add answer below

Comment: i'shall be waiting, and please do in details as i have no idea how to deal with itunesConnect properly.

Comment: You dont need to handle anything on itunesConnect's side, just need to create new version for same app.

Comment: No man, what i meant, at appstore level, i need to update the B app with A app, meant that both app users will get only one app in result..

Answer (score 0):

Open code of App "B", and inside Xcode, select your "Target", go to "General" tab, change Bundle Identifier to App A's bundle Identifier. Update Version number and build number as well. Also update provisioning profiles and upload build. Viola!! This new app will be sent as an update to App A.

Comment: friend, this is what i know, i asked it on itunesConnect, this is i know how to do it, what i meant was to transfer the whole app to another app, by this process the existing user of 'A' app will not receive any update with new app..

Comment: No, I don't think this is possible in itunes.